# java - Eclipse won't export with declared source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

I'm trying to export my Java game as a `Runnable` Jar which works, but when I open it up I get an error that my files aren't present.

Picture of error:

[image: Picture of error]

Picture of res folder in eclipse:

[image: Picture of res folder in eclipse]

The game runs perfectly fine in Eclipse.

I have added the res folder as a source folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a jar file are not `java.io.File`s. Understand that you don't *actually* care about the files, you want their *contents*, so start using [getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))--it works for both cases pretty transparently.

Comment: Why can't I do it my way though?

Comment: When they're in a jar, they're not files in your file system any more. So you can't use the classes meant just for reading files like FileInputStream.